# MVC.NET old data comes back after refresh of screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created jquery ajax call in my view page and this successfully posts data.
However, if I press ctrl+F5 to force browser refresh, old data comes back.

If I close down browser and revisit the site, it now shows updated data.

Following is my action in controller.

I am fairly new to MVC.NET and I am sure there is something I am missing.
Can you please advise?

I truly appreciate in advance.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("EditCategory")]
public ActionResult EditCategory(miniCateObj[] items)
{
    int id = int.Parse(items[0].id.Replace("'",""));
    string newName = items[0].cateName.Replace("'", "");
    ModelState.Remove("CategoryName");
    ModelState.Clear();

    Category model = _categoryService.GetCategoryByCategoryId( id);
    model.CategoryName = newName;

    _categoryService.UpdateCategorySite(model);
    return View(model);
}
```

And following is the ajax call I'm using

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("EditCategory", "CloSite")',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "items": [{
            "id": "'" + id + "'",
            "cateName": "'" + obj.val() + "'"
        }]
    }),
    dataType: "application/xml-urlencode",
    success: function () {
        alert('Success');
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Also, I'm not using ORM / Entity Framework. I had problem the projects .savechanges() not updating(in Entity Framework), so I ended up writing direct SQL to update as following,

```
public int UpdateByCategoryId(int categoryId, string cateName) {
    using(var connection = this.Context.Database.Connection) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connection.ConnectionString)) connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationHelper.ConnectionString;
        var query = string.Format(@"UPDATE Categories set CategoryName = '{0}' where Id = {1}", cateName, categoryId);

        return connection.Execute(query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your jQuery code please. After successful ajax call what you are doing?

Comment: Is `_categoryService` using an ORM of some sort, like Entity Framework?

Comment: Thank you Simple Man & Tierson for your comments. I added "ajax code" and sql code that I'm using to the post.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability because you are directly appending the input from the AJAX request.  You should use a parameterized query rather than constructing it by appending (formatting).

Comment: Do you know if the action is being invoked or is it possibly returning a server-side-cached response?

Comment: Yeap, you're absolutely correct tvanfosson. I am aware of the sql injection problem, that was the next thing I was going to tackle. And I know the action is being invoked since I see the change in database instantly.

And thank you very much for your hint. I am going to investigate if it is indeed "server-side-cached" response. 

Truly thank you!